# Open a Locked Text File with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, locking

When I try to

```
BULK INSERT table FROM 'c:\file.txt'
```

I get

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "c:\file.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.).
```

error since the file is a log file opened by another process.

However with C# I can open the file with `System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite` as:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("c:\\file.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                file = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to have that ReadWrite share functionality within SQL Server (bulk insert or any other)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have control over the OpenFile flags that SQL Server uses behind the scenes, you may have to copy the file to a temporary file prior to doing the bulk insert.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(Reposted from my answer on DBA.SE since you deleted the question.)</sup>

[`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) attempts to take a write lock on the source file to ensure that no other process is concurrently modifying the file while the read occurs. This is done to stabilize the file format, since a read could end up attempting to process a partial line being written by a concurrent writer.

Because the log file is opened for writing by another process already, this is incompatible access, and you get that error.

About the code:

- [`FileAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f.aspx) determines what *you* are going to do with the file.
- [`FileShare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) determines what *others* are allowed to do with the file while you have it open.

The logging process would use `FileAccess.Write` or `FileAccess.ReadWrite`, and given that your code succeeds, probably `FileShare.Read` -- this would prevent others from writing to the file simultaneously, but allows them to read the contents. Your code only requests read access, and so this is compatible. If you re-run the code and request write access (`FileAccess.Write`) instead, the code will fail.

To use `BULK INSERT` to import this file, you'll have to make a copy and import that, then there won't be any file locks involved.